# Amortized Runtime Cost for an algorithm alternating between O(n^2) & O(n^4)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, theory

If I implement an algorithm that runs at `O(n^4)` at the current timestep and then `O(n^2)` at the next.

- is the complexity still the `max[O(n^4), O(n^2)]` ?
- Is there a way to get a polynomial in the range `[2, 4)` for the complexity? I.e something like `O(n^2.83)` on average
- How would I calculate the average runtime cost amortized from `t=0...inf` ? Is it just `[O(n^2) + O(n^4)] / 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*O(n<sup>2</sup>)* is negligible over  *O(n<sup>4</sup>)* since the quotient of the first on the second has a zero limit when *n* grows indefinitely.

So your algorithm is just *O(n<sup>4</sup>)*

Read wikipage on [Big 0 notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and any good textbooks about limits of polynomials.